# VisualForce alternatives? What are people using for BIG projects?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, force.com

Are people using VF for large, complex front ends?  or are people primarily using other front end frameworks and just hitting Force.com for backend data storage, authentication, etc?

Comment: Most of our newer apps are built using AngularJS, RequireJS, and a Visualforce container using JS remoting.

Comment: Even smaller projects these days are pure HTML and JS, no Visualforce more than styling.

Comment: We use 98% VisualForce for nearly everything. It's very quick to develop complex UI, and no discussion about what colour it should be. Having said that, clients always get excited to see HTML5/JS front ends so whenever they're willing to pay for it, we do it.